# JavaScript While Loop Variable Returning NaN

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, while-loop, nan

I'm making a Numerology conversion web app with JavaScript and HTML5. I've ran into a strange issue with a variable and loops. Below is my whole project in its current form.

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Numerology Project</h1>
<form>
    Month:<br>
    <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="userInputMonth" id='userInputMonth'>
    <br>
    Day:<br>
    <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="userInputDay" id='userInputDay'>
    <br>
    Year:<br>
    <input type="text" maxlength="4" name="userInputYear" id='userInputYear'>
    <br><br>
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="userInputFirstName" id='userInputFirstName'>
    <br>
    Middle Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="userInputMiddleName" id='userInputMiddleName'>
    <br>
    Last Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="userInputLastName" id='userInputLastName'>
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" name="Calculate" onclick="BirthDayCalculation()"/>
</form>
<p id="LLNResult"></p>
<br>
<p id="OPNResult"></p>
<br>
<p id="SNResult"></p>
<br>
<p id="PODNResult"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Defined var 
var LLNTemp1;
var LLNTemp2;
var LLNReduce1;
var LLNReduce2;
var NameTemp1;
var NameTemp2;
var OPNReduce1;
var OPNReduce2;
var SNReduce1;
var SNReduce2;
var PODNReduce1;
var PODNReduce2;
function BirthDayCalculation() {
    var Reduction1 = 0;
    var LLNReduceFinal2 = 0;
    var Day = document.getElementById('userInputDay').value;
    var Month = document.getElementById('userInputMonth').value;
    var Year = document.getElementById('userInputYear').value;
    var FirstName = document.getElementById('userInputFirstName').value;
    var MiddleName = document.getElementById('userInputMiddleName').value;
    var LastName = document.getElementById('userInputLastName').value;
    var LLN = ("" + Day + Month + Year).toString();
    var FullName = ("" + FirstName + MiddleName + LastName).toString().toUpperCase();
    var FullNameLength = parseInt(FullName.length);
    var LLNLength = parseInt(("" + Day + Month + Year).length);
    var i = 0;
    var LLNTemp2 = 0;
    while (i < LLNLength) {
        LLNTemp1 = parseInt(LLN.charAt(i));
        LLNTemp2 += LLNTemp1;
        i++;
    }
    if (LLNTemp2 > 9) {
        var i = 0;
        var a = parseInt(LLNTemp2.toString().length);
        var LLNReduceFinal1 = 0;
        var LLNTemp3String = LLNTemp2.toString();
            while (i < a) {
            LLNReduce1 = parseInt(LLNTemp3String.charAt(i));
            LLNReduceFinal1 += LLNReduce1;
            i++;
            }
        var LLNReduceFinal2 = 0;
        var Reduction1 = LLNReduceFinal1;
        if (LLNReduceFinal1 > 9) {
            var i = 0;
            var a = parseInt(Reduction1.toString().length);
            var LLNTemp3String = Reduction1.toString();
            while (i < a) {
                LLNReduce1 = parseInt(LLNTemp3String.charAt(i));
                LLNReduceFinal2 += LLNReduce1;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    var OPN = 0;
    var SN = 0;
    var PODN = 0;
    var PODNWhole = 0;
    var i = 0;
    while (i < FullNameLength) {
        NameTemp1 = FullName.charAt(i);
        var OPNTemp = 0;
        var SNTemp = 0;
        if (NameTemp1 == "A") SNTemp = 1;
        if (NameTemp1 == "J" || NameTemp1 == "S") OPNTemp = 1;
        if (NameTemp1 == "B" || NameTemp1 == "K" || NameTemp1 == "T") OPNTemp = 2;
        if (NameTemp1 == "C" || NameTemp1 == "L") OPNTemp = 3;
        if (NameTemp1 == "U") SNTemp = 3;
        if (NameTemp1 == "D" || NameTemp1 == "M" || NameTemp1 == "V") OPNTemp = 4;
        if (NameTemp1 == "E") SNTemp = 5;
        if (NameTemp1 == "N" || NameTemp1 == "W") OPNTemp = 5;
        if (NameTemp1 == "F" || NameTemp1 == "X") OPNTemp = 6;
        if (NameTemp1 == "O") SNTemp = 6;
        if (NameTemp1 == "G" || NameTemp1 == "P" || NameTemp1 == "Y") OPNTemp = 7;
        if (NameTemp1 == "H" || NameTemp1 == "Q" || NameTemp1 == "Z") OPNTemp = 8;
        if (NameTemp1 == "I") SNTemp = 9;
        if (NameTemp1 == "R") OPNTemp =9;
        OPN += OPNTemp;
        SN += SNTemp;
        PODNWhole += SNTemp;
        PODNWhole += OPNTemp;
        i++;
    }
    var PODN = PODNWhole
    var OPNReduceFinal = 0;
    if (OPN > 9) {
        var OPNLength = parseInt(OPN.toString().length);        
        var OPNTempString = OPN.toString();
        var i = 0;
        while (i < OPNLength) {
            OPNReduce1 = parseInt(OPNTempString.charAt(i));
            OPNReduceFinal += OPNReduce1;
            i++;
        }
    }
    var SNReduceFinal = 0;
    if (SN > 9) {
        var SNLength = parseInt(SN.toString().length);  
        var SNTempString = SN.toString();
        var i = 0;
        while (i < SNLength) {
            SNReduce1 = parseInt(SNTempString.charAt(i));
            SNReduceFinal += SNReduce1;
            i++;
        }
    }   
    var PODNReduceFinal = 0;
    if (PODN > 9) {
        var PODNLength = parseInt(PODN.toString().length);  
        var PODNTempString = PODN.toString();
        var i = 0;
        while (i < PODNLength) {
            PODNReduce1 = parseInt(PODNTempString.charAt(i));
            PODNReduceFinal += PODNReduce1;
            i++;
        }
//      var PODNReduceFinal = PODNReduce2;
//      var PODN = PODNReduce2;
    }
    var LLNResult = "Your Life Lesson Number Is:" + LLNTemp2 + "/" + Reduction1;
    if (LLNReduceFinal2 != 0) {
        LLNResult = LLNResult + "/" + LLNReduceFinal2;
    }
    var OPNResult = "Your Outer Personality Number is:" + OPN;
    if (OPNReduceFinal != 0) {
        var OPNResult = OPNResult + "/" + OPNReduceFinal;
    }
    var SNResult = "Your Soul Number is:" + SN;
    if (SNReduceFinal != 0) {
        var SNResult = SNResult + "/" + SNReduceFinal;
    }
    var PODNResult = "Your Path of Destiny Number is:" + PODNWhole;
    if (PODNReduceFinal != 0) {
        var PODNResult = PODNResult + "/" + PODNReduceFinal;
    }
    if (LLNTemp2 != 0) {
        document.getElementById("LLNResult").innerHTML = LLNResult;
    }
    if (PODNWhole != 0) {
        document.getElementById("OPNResult").innerHTML = OPNResult;
        document.getElementById("SNResult").innerHTML = SNResult;
        document.getElementById("PODNResult").innerHTML = PODNResult;
    }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So basically you enter your birthday and full name into a form. the script will then convert the name to numbers A = 1, B = 2.... and reduce both to single digits. the numbers will be added one by one. example. 13=4, 55=10, 63=9.

Here is the general code used to make reductions. Let's make PODN = 55

```
var PODNReduceFinal = 0;
var PODN = 55;
if (PODN > 9) {
    var PODNLength = parseInt(PODN.toString().length);  
    var PODNTempString = PODN.toString();
    var i = 0;
    while (i < PODNLength) {
        PODNReduce1 = parseInt(PODNTempString.charAt(i));
        PODNReduceFinal += PODNReduce1;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Currently, it only loops once but I would like to have it get reduced to the lowest number possible. 1 in this case. I was thinking that if I change the if to a while it would accomplish this but it doesn't work the way I thought it would. I tried to make some changes and got stuck in a loop. So I started to troubleshoot. I added another variable to prevent the whole loop from looping infinitely.

```
var PODNReduceFinal = 0;
var PODN = 55;
while (PODN > 9) {
    var PODNLength = parseInt(PODN.toString().length);  
    var PODNTempString = PODN.toString();
    var i = 0;
    while (i < PODNLength) {
        PODNReduce1 = parseInt(PODNTempString.charAt(i));
        PODNReduce2 += PODNReduce1;
        i++;
    }
    var PODNReduceFinal = PODNReduce2;
    var PODN = PODNReduce2;
 }
```

Using this I thought when PODN would be checked by the while loop first it would run through the first steps. Get the length of the number, in this case 2. Convert it to a string so it can pull the digits one by one. Pull the digits in sequence with the length of the loop and convert them to numbers. Add them together in PODNReduce2, 55=10. Set PODNReduceFinal = 10, set PODN = 10. Then return to the first condition and check that PODN is now 10 and is greater than 9. Loop again to reduce further. Doing this until it's a single digit stored in PODNReduceFinal. But that's not what happens. When I try to display PODNReduceFinal I get NaN. Even if I revert the first "while" to "if" it still doesn't work. I'm at a loss. Please help.

Comment: Because you did not define `PODNReduce2` anywhere. 
put `var PODNReduce2 = 0;` at the begining of your code, then it will work

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak That fixes the NaN issue. Thank you. I can't seem to get the while loop to function properly now. Am I misunderstanding how they work? It's an if statement that loops correct? If `PODN < 9` it should skip the loop?